# how to post http request with file upload several times with different file each time Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, jmeter-plugins

I have the following request, with file upload without "multipart/form-data for POST" that is working perfect.
[image]

now I want to run this for several users lets say 5 or 10 but each time with a different file (like taking the file from parameter or csv file or something like this).

couldn't find a way of doing it except of making different samplers each one with a different file, but for let say 1000 files this will be a lot of work.

Comment: what was your configuration for the csv?, i have tried it with csv and it worked fine.

Comment: @ararar - could you please add step by step of how to config the csv to work with different files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace hard-coded `File Path` with a JMeter Variable like: `${filePath}`

[image: JMeter FilePath variable]

Depending on where do you get your file names or paths from this `${filePath}` variable can be populated from:

- [CSV Data Set Config](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG)
- [__StringFromFile()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__StringFromFile) or [__CSVRead()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead) function (by the way, you can put functions directly into the `File Path` field without any interim steps
- [JDBC Test Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Connection_Configuration) if your results are in the database
- [Directory Listing Config](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/introducing-directory-listing-config-plugin-jmeter) plugin can be useful if your files live under a folder and you need to upload them all

Comment: Ok i tried it and its only upload the first file on the list. Then i change the "number of threads (users)" from 1 to 2 (the number of files i have in the csv list) and it worked out. so i need to change the "number of threads (users)" so it reflect the number of files in the list?

Comment: It is up to you, you may decide either to loop the list or to stop when it ends or go through all records and continue.

Comment: if I dont change "number of threads (users)" it will upload only the first file in the list

Answer (score 0):

First of all, create a CSV file with all the name of files you want to upload, the name of the files in the CSV file should include the file extension. 
i.e`My_File.csv`.

Add a [CSV data set config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) prior to your sampler.

And finally replace the **file path** (under files upload tab) to your sampler with the variable name from your CSV data set config.